# Getting Iron Golems through portals

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I led an Iron Golem to my Nether portal and he went through.

He's now in the Nether, but doesn't seem to be able to go back. I pushed him all the way through the portal and nothing happened.

Is he permanently stuck in the Nether now? Can Golems only go through one way?

Update: I have now waited by the portal for 10 minutes, pushing him through periodically. He still won't teleport back.

Comment: Mobs have a high cooldown on going back, like 30 seconds or so. Did you try after some time?

Comment: Have you eliminated the possibility that the golem is just wandering out of the portal blocks too quickly, perhaps by walling it in?

Answer (score 8):

All mobs except those who naturally spawn in the Nether require a 45 second rest time for "they jet-lag the experience teleporting". The mobs that spawn naturally in the nether only require a 15 second lapse before they can be teleported back in. This includes zombie pigmen, magma cubes, and blazes for spawners.

Comment: I've also found that they have to completely exit and enter again, although this could just be a symptom of what you describe